# Can't connect to SphinxQL through PDO but can through terminal on port 9306

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sphinx

I have sphinx for search on shared hosting. I can connect to sphinxql through the terminal, but not using a PDO connection in a php file. It times out. I assume if the hosting company had port 9306 blocked I wouldn't be able to connect through the terminal. Any help is appreciated. Below is the PDO connection.

```
$queryIdx = new PDO("mysql:host=2x8.xxx.xxx.xxx; dbname=xxx; port:9306","stevebushe","xxx")
```

When connecting through terminal I do :

```
mysql -P9306 --protocol=tcp
```

I think what's key here is that in terminal i don't have to specify a database when connecting to where the index resides.With the above terminal connection i can see the index just fine.  If I connect to the associated database, then the index is not available.

I there a way to connect to make a PDO connection without specifying a database ? I get an error "No database selected" when i do that.

Comment: Are you sure your credentials are correct? Are you sure you can connect to the machine remotely? MySQL is generally behind a firewall and for good reason.

Comment: Pass the port in as the 4th parameter. The default port is 3306.

Comment: Yes. I can connect without a problem through the terminal. And I can connect with PDO if I don't specify port 9306.

Comment: Wait, you *can* connect if you don't specify a port, but you *can't* if you do? So then don't specify a port? Or if you need to, show how you're passing the port in.

Comment: Hi Aynber .. I just edited the question with more detail on the  connection information for both PDO and terminal

Comment: Solved. Port specifications in the configuration must be set to 3306 or server default. while the pdo connection for some reason has to be set to port 9306. this works flawlessly for some reason. My brain for some reason expects all ports to be the same...maybe because my brain tries to be logical

Comment: Well you do need to configure sphinx/searchd to listen on the same port that connecting with. Its just if you dont specify it will listen on 9306 by default. Its proably the address (not port) that tripping you up. In the initial pdo specifying the public ip address, but the CLI command using localhost. Your final command (in answer) did use localhost. (if you dont specfy port then connecting to mysql (not sphinx) hence the db being required.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Listening Port specifications in the configuration sphinx.conf must be set to 3306  or server defaul . While the pdo connection for some reason has to be set to port 9306 also on 127.0.0.1. Without specifying the database name on the dsn [which is optional according Docs]. This works flawlessly for some reason. I am now getting all search data.

```
$queryIdx = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=9306","username","password");
```